# How to decode JSON with objects as string values in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a response which looks similar to this and I am trying to decode this using Swift's JSONDecoder.

```
{
   "root": "{\"directory\": {\"id\":1}}",
}
```

My structs look like this

```
struct Root: Codable {
    var directory: Directory
}

struct Directory: Codable {
    var id: Int
}
```

The problem now seems to be that the value of root is actually a String and not a Dictionary like Swift would expect during the decoding, causing it to crash.

Is there a way I can decode this with JSONDecoder?

Comment: Ask the owner of the service to send something more consistent. A “second level” JSON string is pretty cumbersome. The root object is `let root : String`

Comment: That would be ideal I know, but unfortunately I cannot influence this right now

Comment: I believe this is an exact duplicate of the linked answer. Ping me here if you believe that doesn't address your issue and we can take another look.

Comment: The linked answer solved my problem, thanks for sharing it I unfortunately couldn't find it